# How can I do hyperparameter optimization for a CNN-LSTM neural network?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, hyperparameter-optimization, hyper-parameters

I have built a CNN-LSTM neural network with 2 inputs and 2 outputs in Keras. I trained the network with `model.fit_generator()` (and not `model.fit()`), to load just parts of the training data when needed, because the training data is too large to load at once.

After the training the model was not working. So I checked training data (before and after augmentation). The training data are correct. So I thought the reason why the model does not work must be that I have not found the optimal hyperparameters yet.

But how can I do hyperparameter optimization on a network with multiple inputs and outputs and trained with `model.fit_generator()`? All I can find online is hyperparameter optimization of networks with a single input and single output and trained with `model.fit()`.

Comment: The model not working does not mean that the hyperparameters is the problem. More often than not even with wrong hyperparameters a model should work but just not work that well. What data are you using? Maybe you can try using a more simple LSTM model first before trying a CNN LSTM model.